# Removing all objects that have a property/value duplicate BUT the last

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates

I need to loop through an array of objects where each object will have an email property. My goal is to loop through the data (CSV) and if any record has the same email, I need to remove all but the last as that will be the value that I need to update in the end. I can't seem to get this right.

I have tried using .find but I never quite made it all the way. I feel like I need to add to it but I'm hazy as to what.

```
let arr = [
  {name: 'stefano', email: 'stef@mail.com'},
  {name: 'steve', email: 'cuck@mail.com'},
  {name: 'weave', email: 'stef@mail.com'},
  {name: 'peave', email: 'luck@mail.com'}
  ];

 let keepLast = arr.find( (obj,idx) => {
    let found = 0;
    if(obj.email === 'stef@mail.com') {
      ++found;
    }
    if(found > 1) {
      // Somehow remove the previous iteration catch on match
    }
  });
```

This is about where I am. I feel like I need to somehow keep memory of the last index so I know to remove it as soon as I find another one.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for finding that. I will read through it right now and delete this if it's the case. I looked for a bit but had a hard time finding one specifically only maintaining last duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd `reduce` into an object indexed by the email, thereby overwriting the previous object at that email key if it exists. Then just take that object's values:

```js
let arr = [
  {name: 'stefano', email: 'stef@mail.com'},
  {name: 'steve', email: 'cuck@mail.com'},
  {name: 'weave', email: 'stef@mail.com'},
  {name: 'peave', email: 'luck@mail.com'}
];

const output = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((a, obj) => {
    a[obj.email] = obj;
    return a;
  }, {})
);
console.log(output);
```